# First install of TensorFlow gives error when tried validating the installation. CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, nvidia

I'm running with conda env keras with jupyter notebook. First got installed only CPU, then installed for GPU. Tried make another env only with GPU TF but still same error.
Can someone give me direction? 
EDIT: Operation is standard, CUDA 9.0 installed and at C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin have file cudnn64_7.dll inserted.

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

    2018-02-15 10:52:30.240960: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructi
ons that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2018-02-15 10:52:30.410969: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with pro
perties:
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.392
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.86GiB
2018-02-15 10:52:30.410969: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow dev
ice (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0
1:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-02-15 10:52:32.394083: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 3.53G (
3790774272 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.482088: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 3.18G (
3411696640 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.527090: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 2.86G (
3070526976 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.551092: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 2.57G (
2763474176 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.574093: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 2.32G (
2487126784 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.595094: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 2.08G (
2238414080 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.613095: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 1.88G (
2014572800 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.629096: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 1.69G (
1813115648 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.645097: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 1.52G (
1631804160 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:32.658098: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 1.37G (
1468623872 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-02-15 10:52:43.783734: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\3
6\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow dev
ice (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0
1:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

Comment: Did you install the proper CuDNN libraries along with the appropriate CUDA toolkit?

Comment: @SimbarasheTimothyMotsi yes I installed CUDA 9.0 and cudnn64_7.dll inserted in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin.

Comment: did you install the cuDNN v6.0 files in the path with other .dll files?

Comment: I unzipped cuDNN 7.0.5 for CUDA 9.0, took cudnn64_7.dll and pasted in bin folder with CUDA installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was typo at installation instructions from official site. At GitHub was written CuDNN 7.

Answer (score 0):

you need CuDNN V6.0, you can check the requirements https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

check under "Requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support"

Comment: I had installed V6. That caused that it was missing CUDA 8.0. Here https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download there is no v6 for CUDA 9.0.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention CuDNN libraries go along with their toolkits. My bad, glad its working now.

Comment: It is not working. I have installed CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7. Really do not know why tensorflow site suggests to install CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 6. It doesnt fit.

Comment: from my understanding cuda 8.0 goes hand in  hand with CuDNN 6.0, and cudnn64_7.dll is also essential. Most people forget to place the CUDA files in system path